# Why is "Free Storage Space" in AWS RDS measured in MB/Sec?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to set up a cloudwatch trigger to send me an email when my RDS database (MySQL) capacity is low, but when I'm configuring (and also monitoring) the Free Storage Space metric, it's measured in MB/Sec. The current max capacity is 20,000 MB/Sec which is equivalent to the 20gb limit I have, but I want to make sure I'm looking at the right metric. Is this the right metric? And if so, why is it measured per second?

[image]

Comment: Quite some time has passed and this is still bugged.

Comment: @TomasGonzalez Yeah it doesn't appear that AWS is keen on addressing this but at least I'm somewhat confident it's just standard storage space.

Answer (score 2):

[FreeStorageSpace](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-cloudwatch.html#rds-metrics) is in `Bytes`:

[image]

Also, the use of this metric to create alarm is explained in detail in:

- [How can I create CloudWatch alarms to monitor the Amazon RDS free storage space and prevent storage full issues?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/storage-full-rds-cloudwatch-alarm/)

Comment: So it seems like the best way to do it is to set it up in cloudwatch rather than setting up an alarm within the RDS page.
I edited my post to show that when configuring an alarm or monitoring performance on RDS, the "Free Storage Space" is measured in mb/second. Until I figure out what that means I'm going to stick with setting up alarms in cloudwatch.

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter how you set up the alarm. The effect is the same. It seems however that there's a prominent bug in the unit display of this metric. I had the same question and ended up here so I'm assuming there's no good reason the unit reads mb/second.